# Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0

Tags: angularjs, json

I am getting this error in console when i click submit button though my data is getting saved to backend as i wanted.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at dc (angular.min.js:91)
    at angular.min.js:92
    at q (angular.min.js:7)
    at gd (angular.min.js:92)
    at f (angular.min.js:94)
    at angular.min.js:131
    at m.$digest (angular.min.js:142)
    at m.$apply (angular.min.js:146)
    at l (angular.min.js:97)
```

Here is my frontend code in angular

```
  $scope.nextStep = function() {
        if ($scope.selection === 'Information'){
            $scope.branch.organisation = $scope.branch.organisation.id;
            $scope.fact.incrementStep($scope);
        }
        else if ($scope.selection === 'Validation'){
            var authdata = base64.encode($rootScope.globals.currentUser.user.phone + ':' + $scope.password.password);
            if (authdata === $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata){
                $scope.passwordMatch = true;

                var branchArr = [];
                var dynamicBranches = $scope.dynamicBranches;

                for (var i = 0; i < dynamicBranches.length; i++) {
                  branchArr.push(dynamicBranches[i].name);
                }

                var params = [{
                    "region" : $scope.branch.region,
                    "branches" : branchArr
                }];

                Restangular.one('organisation', $scope.branch.organisation).all('add_region_and_branch_data').post(params).then(function(response) {
                     $scope.createdBranch = response;
                     $scope.fact.incrementStep($scope);
                 }, function(error){
                     ///console.log('Error with status', error.statusText, 'code', error.status);
                     //SweetAlert.swal('Error', 'The agent couldn\'t be created. \n' + error.data.error, 'error');
                     console.log(error);
                 });


            }else{
                $scope.passwordMatch = false;
            }
        }
    };
```

Again, my data is getting saved to api but I am getting this error. How can i fix this?

Comment: You need to debug. What is your service returning? It's likely invalid JSON because of some error on their side.

Answer (score 1):

Check your HTTP-response body. AngularJS gets something what it can't parse like JSON. May be any warning or error happened and added to your API-response? I thing a problem is not in your `nextStep` function.

`Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0` problem can happen, for example, with this HTTP-responses:

```
Too many params warning{"here": "is valid JSON"}
```

Or just warning

```
Too many params warning
```

Comment: I need to send data in this format [{ "region": "matlab", "branches": ["B","C"] }] with a organisation_id.

Comment: @SalmanMahmud Unfortunately I can't help you without HTTP request and response dump. Could you show data from Chrome DevTools Network tab for this request?